# Entering Skills Proficiency in People Profile

Tags: user-profile

We are considering implementing a predefined listing of skills for people to choose from when updating their profile in MOSS. How can we add the ability for each person to also include their proficiency for each skill, i.e, database design-expert, web developer-proficient, photo editing-beginner.
Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a profile property in your Shared Service Provider and indicate to Allow multiple values as well as Allow a choice list, then you can create your pre-defined choice list using the descriptions you have indicated above. You will want to have as many entries per skill as you will have levels. This will give you the ability to control those predefines skills and levels and yet the flexibility to allow the user to select all that apply to them.

Answer (score 0):

what about defining sets of custom User Profile Properties, like:

- Skill1
- Proficiency1
- Skill2
- Proficiency2
- Skill3
- Proficiency3
- Skill4
- Proficiency4
- Skill5
- Proficiency5

Answer (score 0):

I heard that in one of the SPC09 sessions, there was a demonstration of a custom ASP.Net component writing to a proprietary database to solve complex People Profile issues at Deloite. I wonder if they would do it the same today since it is a > 2 year old solution.